# Load more items with nextTokenPage

Tags: android, listview, playlist

I searched a lot but not find proper solution.
I'm trying to get **youtube** playlist into the **listview** android (using android studio) with my api key but getting only 50 results.I read that we need to use **nextTokenPage** to load more items when scroll down.I am trying hard to make this work but now almost giving up. Please, can anyone guide me how to go with this?
Thank you!

This is my activity code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {

            String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLR0ZsFRT-s0NcdVh-Sq4uBe8SHdjHY7S5&key=AIzaSyBQbE0gmhtaRHBFpecmKDGAIH0uLwe3e9k";

            String response = getUrlString(url);


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject video = jsonObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("resourceId");jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("resourceId");
                String title = jsonObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                String id = video.getString("videoId");


                String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default").getString("url");jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default").getString("url");


                displaylist = new Videos(title, thumbUrl, id);
                displaylistArray.add(displaylist);
            }


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the api refrence you will get **nextPageToken** and **prevPageToken** after this "initial call" if more pages available. The next request must be include the **pageToken** with the content of **nextPageToken** or **prevPageToken**.

Please have a look at [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).

Also have a look at the [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#examples).

Comment: thanks, i already read it. but i cant do it inside my code. if some one have working examlpe it will be great. or explane me were to put the code inside my work it will help me too.